# How to shorten description on listview in android

Tags: android, listview

i have a simple question.I am loading items on the fist activity such as Image,Title,Rating,Genre and Description.The problem is the description on my first activity,i would like to shorten it,jus like the one in my second activity instead of displaying it in full like it is doing in the first activty on the listview as it expands the height of the list.i would like to display one line and the full description on another activty.Any way on how to do it?If you need i post more code i'll be happy to.

[image: The description of the first activity to shorten like in the second activity using (.....)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your description TextView:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Comment: Thanks,this was so simple.I appreciate

Answer (score 3):

you can use those two properties:

`android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"`

With those two values you get a max of two lines and some "..." behind the text in case there is more text

Answer (score 1):

Try this property of TextView in your layout file.
`android:ellipsize="end"     android:singleLine="true"`

Comment: android:singleLine="true" will automatically ellipsize the end of the line, no need to also have android:ellipsize="end"

Answer (score 1):

You can ellipse the the TextView you are using for the description view as

```
 android:ellipsize="end"
```

and set the width of the TextView to match the item parent.